# Recording Doors

Tags: sound-effects-recording, library-sound-effects, microphone-technique, microphone-positioning

What's the best way to record household doors opening and closing? My own recordings are always a bit too transient and thin sounding whereas the ones in my commercial library are chunky, thick and more powerful and always get used more in my tracklaying.

Is it a case of setting up multiple mics - a close up dynamic mic and one placed further back or just simply a case of single mic choice and placement? Or is it all in the post processing?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you have a recording of doors you like (the library ones). If that's true, couldn't you just use those?

Comment: I do use them, but for various reasons I'd like to be able to record and collect my own. It's always good to learn about these things too to improve mic skills etc. The quest for knowledge and all that.

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude but how long have you experimented with it? You came up with methods such as dynamic mic and another placed further back which is a good start. Why not try it for your self? A lot of learning comes from actually doing and it can be applied to many other things in the future. Not a lot of real world affects has little processing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a little space between you and the door and aiming your mics more towards the middle of the door rather than the latch?

Comment: Questions should not be part of answer. I suggest editing this answer.

Comment: I don't think there really is a true answer to this question. It's just trial and error.